# Clang does not link libraries statically, even with the -static flag

Tags: c++, compilation, dependencies, clang

I am using MinGW64 clang and trying to compile a c++ program to run. The compilation is successful, and I can run the executable on my machine.

However, running the executable on a different machine I get a `The code execution cannot proceed because vulkan-1.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem`.

I tried linking my dependencies statically, using the `-static` flag but that did not make a difference.

I compiled the executable using make on windows.

Makefile:

```
BUILD_DIR := ./build
SRC_DIR := ./src
INCLUDE_DIR := ./include

# In build dir
TARGET_EXEC := test.exe

COMPILER_EXEC := clang++
COMPILER_ARGS := -iquote "$(INCLUDE_DIR)" -I "./external/GLFW/include" -I "./external/vulkan/include" -static -Wdeprecated -Werror -Wall -Wextra
LINKER_ARGS := -L "./external/glfw/lib-mingw-w64" -L "./external/vulkan/lib" -l:libglfw3.a -l:vulkan-1.lib -lgdi32 -Wdeprecated -Werror -Wall -Wextra


rwildcard = $(foreach d,$(wildcard $(1:=/*)),$(call rwildcard,$(d),$(2)) $(filter $(subst *,%,$(2)),$(d)))

SRC_FILES := $(call rwildcard,$(SRC_DIR),*.cpp)
OBJECT_FILES := $(SRC_FILES:%=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)

.DELETE_ON_ERROR:
.PHONY: all
all: $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET_EXEC)

# Final executable
$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET_EXEC): $(OBJECT_FILES)
    $(COMPILER_EXEC) $(OBJECT_FILES) $(LINKER_ARGS) -o $@

# Build for c++ sources
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.cpp.o: %.cpp
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(COMPILER_EXEC) $(COMPILER_ARGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: test
test:
    $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET_EXEC)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -r $(BUILD_DIR)
```

ldd output:

```
$ ldd build/test.exe
        ntdll.dll => /c/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7fff30790000)
        KERNEL32.DLL => /c/Windows/System32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x7fff2fa30000)
        KERNELBASE.dll => /c/Windows/System32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7fff2dda0000)
        msvcrt.dll => /c/Windows/System32/msvcrt.dll (0x7fff2ff40000)
        USER32.dll => /c/Windows/System32/USER32.dll (0x7fff2f880000)
        win32u.dll => /c/Windows/System32/win32u.dll (0x7fff2e270000)
        vulkan-1.dll => /c/Windows/SYSTEM32/vulkan-1.dll (0x7ffed7fc0000)
        GDI32.dll => /c/Windows/System32/GDI32.dll (0x7fff30510000)
        gdi32full.dll => /c/Windows/System32/gdi32full.dll (0x7fff2e150000)
        msvcp_win.dll => /c/Windows/System32/msvcp_win.dll (0x7fff2dd00000)
        ucrtbase.dll => /c/Windows/System32/ucrtbase.dll (0x7fff2e3e0000)
        ADVAPI32.dll => /c/Windows/System32/ADVAPI32.dll (0x7fff30460000)
        SHELL32.dll => /c/Windows/System32/SHELL32.dll (0x7fff2e5a0000)
        sechost.dll => /c/Windows/System32/sechost.dll (0x7fff30340000)
        RPCRT4.dll => /c/Windows/System32/RPCRT4.dll (0x7fff30220000)
        CFGMGR32.dll => /c/Windows/SYSTEM32/CFGMGR32.dll (0x7fff2d880000)
        VCRUNTIME140.dll => /c/Windows/SYSTEM32/VCRUNTIME140.dll (0x7fff009c0000)
```

How can I link my libraries statically, so I don't have to worry about missing dlls?

Comment: Do you have a static version of the vulkan library? Your code presumably won't work anyway without a vulkan driver which would provide the dll?

Comment: I am using the [Vulkan LunarG SDK](https://www.lunarg.com/vulkan-sdk/), and I am not sure on how to identify if I have static versions (I have `.lib` files if that helps). Also the code won't work but I want to provide the user a more friendlier message than a missing dll.

Comment: @Adamiok I guess the static versions would have a `.a` suffix. The `.lib` versions are probably *import libraries* which are used for dynamic linking. Static and shared libraries are just different things. If you want to link with static libraries you have to have those libraries in the first place.

Comment: @Adamiok Simple test for import libraries. Are the `.lib` files much, much smaller than the corresponding `.dll` files? If yes, then they are import libraries, if not than *maybe* they are static libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But there are no other files than the includes (`.h`) and the (`.lib`) files. Will have to check if Vulkan even redistributes static libraries.

Comment: @Adamiok Your dependencies say `vulkan-1.dll => /c/Windows/SYSTEM32/vulkan-1.dll` so presumably when you installed vulkan it copied the DLL there. Does seem like the `.lib` is an import library.

Comment: @john That is probably what happened, the vulkan installer installed the dll there. So can I link to that dll and it will work. Or do I have to package the dll with the application and redistribute it that way?

Comment: @Adamiok No, you link with the import library, the import library contains code which loads the vulkan dll at runtime (that's basically the definition of an import library). So you have to package the dll with your application (assuming the vulkan license permits you to do this).